# How do you trigger a click on the <button></button> element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I know this might be very simple but I can't get it to work. I am trying to trigger a click on a  on page load. Below is the code I am using.

HTML

```
<button class="triggerme"></button>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".triggerme").trigger("click");
});
```

I can't change it to an input, or anchor.

Comment: you dont have a click event what is there to trigger?

Comment: No, it should just trigger on load.

Comment: maybe it's on a form, then default action is submit?

Comment: have you tried .click()? --->
$( ".triggerme" ).click();

Comment: @MathijsSegers is not in a form, it's just a button that opens up a dialog box.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code , I think problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @GovindSamrow I don't even know anymore. I changed the element to an anchor, and nothing is working now.

Comment: What will happen on button click?

Comment: @GovindSamrow just show a div which looks like a modal. It is not bootstrap or fancybox, so I can't just call them instead.

Comment: Share your full code or create fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".triggerme" ).click(function() {
     alert( "You clicked on triggerme" );
    });
});
```

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<button class="triggerme btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
```

try this..

Comment: this works when you click it, but does not tigger click on page load.

Comment: if you want to make it happen automatically when page loads then just replace with this                   $(document).ready(function(){
               setTimeout(function() {
         $( ".triggerme" ).trigger('click');
               alert( "You clicked on triggerme" );
          },1000);
      });

Comment: try this.. it will work when page loads and you can give Timeout also as much you want..

Comment: Will do later. Lights went off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$( ".triggerme" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".triggerme").click()
    {
    enter code here to execute on button press
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.